# Do you burn fat directly if you only eat protein?

Tags: protein, energy

If you only eat protein and workout with weightlifting, does your body burn fat for energy or digest your muscles or use the protein you’ve eaten?

Comment: If you follow a protein only diet for too long you may experience nutritional deficiencies. You also may not have enough fiber. This can lead to constipation and could increase your risk for some types of cancer.